# jQuery .toggle() button needs to be clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm trying to do two things:

1. load the Disqus script `embed.js` after the "Show comments" button is clicked.
2. Hide the `disqus_thread` div via the same button while changing the text in the button.

The problem is that after page load, I have to click "Show Comments" twice; the first click loads the `embed.js` and that should toggle `disqus_thread` to visible, but I have to click a second time to see the `disqus_thread`. (It doesn't matter than `embed.js` is loaded; I only want to toggle the div and hide it.)

Note: the `{{ }}` constructs in `showComments()` are [hugo](/questions/tagged/hugo), but I don't think they are the issue.

```
    <button id="disqus-button" onclick="showComments()">Show comments</button>
    
    <script>
    
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#disqus-button').click(function(){
        $('#disqus_thread').toggle();
        $(this).text( $(this).text() == 'Show Comments' ? "Hide Comments" : "Show Comments");
    });
    });
    
    </script>
    
    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    
    <script>
    
    function showComments() {
        var disqus_config = function () {
        {{with .Params.disqus_identifier }}this.page.identifier = '{{ . }}';{{end}}
        {{with .Params.disqus_title }}this.page.title = '{{ . }}';{{end}}
        {{with .Params.disqus_url }}this.page.url = '{{ . | html  }}';{{end}}
        };
        var d = document, s = d.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
        s.src = '//' + "{{ .Site.DisqusShortname }}" + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
        (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: have you tried removing `onClick` and adding `showComments()` inside the click function in jQuery ?

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `#disqus_thread` should be hidden on start (as no comments are loaded)
2. `showComments()` should be renamed, that's  not its work, perhaps `loadComments()` is a better name.
3. it should be checked if `embed.js` is already loaded and just execute that code once.
4. once that is completed, is just a toggle visibility and change button text.

```
    <button id="disqus-button">Show Comments</button>

    <div id="disqus_thread" style="display:none">adasd</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

    <script>
        function showComments() {
            console.log('Show comments');

            //checking if embed.js is already loaded. This should just be done
            //once.
            if ($('script[src*="embed.js"]').length == 0) {
                //original code on showComments().
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '#disqus-button', function() {
                showComments();
                $('#disqus_thread').toggle();
                $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Hide Comments' ? "Show Comments" : "Hide Comments");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. I only had to change `$(this).text($(this).text() == 'Hide Comments' ? "Show Comments" : "Hide Comments");`

Comment: Sure! That's right. I edit my answer and you can mark as correct if it solves the issue

Comment: Thanks! I have to wait 8 hours to award the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `trigger` function.

Here is the example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="disqus-button">Show Comments</button>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#disqus-button').click(function () {
            showComments();
            if ($(this).text() == 'Show Comments') {
                $(this).text("Hide Comments");
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#disqus-button').trigger("click");
                }, 1000);
            }
            else {
                $(this).text("Show Comments");
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="disqus_thread"></div>

<script>

    function showComments() {
        console.log('show comments');
        // var disqus_config = function () {
        //     { { with.Params.disqus_identifier } } this.page.identifier = '{{ . }}'; { { end } }
        //     { { with.Params.disqus_title } } this.page.title = '{{ . }}'; { { end } }
        //     { { with.Params.disqus_url } } this.page.url = '{{ . | html  }}'; { { end } }
        // };
        // var d = document, s = d.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
        // s.src = '//' + "{{ .Site.DisqusShortname }}" + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        // s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
        // (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, and that shows the comments on first click, but doesn't hide them, and the button text doesn't change.

Comment: Can you try again? If you click the show comment button, after 1 second the click trigger occur.

Comment: Why do I want a timeout? And it simply doesn't work; it does not hide/show.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the code, the issue is the `<div id="disqus_thread"></div>`  is initially not set to be hidden.

So on first click, the call to `$('#disqus_thread').toggle();` will hide the div. And the second click sets it back to visible. And I believe the button text would be out of sync with the toggle in this case.

If that is the issue, the following can fix the issue,

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#disqus-button').click(function(){
       ....
    });

    $('#disqus_thread').hide(); // hide it initially when loading the page 
   });
```

Alternatively you can also set the *style='display:none'* to disqus_thread div directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a window level variable to check if `disqusJs` script was added or not in click handler after toggling div that way you will toggle content as well as load script on first click.

```js
disqusJsScriptAdded = false;

function loadDisqusJs() {
  //var disqus_config = function () {
  // {{with .Params.disqus_identifier }}this.page.identifier = '{{ . }}';{{end}}
  // {{with .Params.disqus_title }}this.page.title = '{{ . }}';{{end}}
  // {{with .Params.disqus_url }}this.page.url = '{{ . | html  }}';{{end}}
  //};
  disqusJsScriptAdded = true;
 
  var d = document,
    s = d.createElement('script');
  s.async = true;
  s.src = '//' + "{{ .Site.DisqusShortname }}" + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
  s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
  (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#disqus-button').click(function() {
    $('#disqus_thread').toggle();
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Show Comments' ? "Hide Comments" : "Show Comments");
    
    if (!disqusJsScriptAdded) {
      loadDisqusJs();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#disqus_thread {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="disqus-button">Show comments</button>
<div id="disqus_thread">
  This is content of the thread!
</div>
```